# How can I press the title in titlepaindicator and go to this fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using in my app TitlePageIndicator with ViewPager and works fine. I can swicht right and left and all works ok. The problem is that I've saw in other apps that if you touch one of the titles in the viewpager you can go to this screen, too. But not sure how can I do it.

Thanks in advance

MainActivity

```
 private ViewPager pager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        this.pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(Europe.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.colorAccent), "Europe"));
        adapter.addFragment(America.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.colorAccent), "America"));
        adapter.addFragment(Asia.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.colorAccent), "Asia"));
        adapter.addFragment(Africa.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), "Africa"));
        adapter.addFragment(Oceania.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.colorAccent), "Oceania"));

        this.pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);


        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        indicator.setFooterColor(R.color.setTextColor);
        indicator.setFooterLineHeight(1 * density); //1dp
        indicator.setFooterIndicatorHeight(3 * density); //3dp
        indicator.setFooterIndicatorStyle(TitlePageIndicator.IndicatorStyle.Underline);
        indicator.setTextColor(0xAA000000);
        indicator.setTextSize(60);

        indicator.setSelectedColor(R.color.setTextColor);
        indicator.setSelectedBold(true);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    }
```

FragmentAdapter

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] titles = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
    private List<Fragment> fragments;


    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    }


    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragments.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return one.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
            case 1:
                return two.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
            case 2:
                return three.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
            case 3:
                return four.newInstance(3, "Page # 4");
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried TabLayout in android http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Comment: What's the point in touching those titles if you are in that current page of your fragment? And The title switches every time you go to another fragment.

Comment: Yes, exactly that you said